# Can't authenticate with token

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-roles, thinktecture-ident-model

I've a ASP.NET MVC website which uses an ASP.NET WebAPI to authenticate. I've using ThinkTecture IdentityModel for basic authentication and session token, which works fine locally and in Azure Websites. However, I had to migrate to Azure Cloud services and now I can't authenticate with the token, always receiving the 401 error, but with just username and password works fine.

The only difference I can guess is that I've to deal with IIS now. Is there any modification required to allow authentication with token?

**UPDATED:**

I'm not using any Web.Config configuration for authentication, just using the following code in WebAPIConfig.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );

            var authConfig = new AuthenticationConfiguration
                                 {
                                     RequireSsl = true,
                                     EnableSessionToken = true,
                                     SendWwwAuthenticateResponseHeaders = true,
                                     SessionToken = new SessionTokenConfiguration()
                                         {
                                             DefaultTokenLifetime = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0)
                                         }
                                 };

            // setup authentication against membership
            authConfig.AddBasicAuthentication(
                (userName, password) => WebSecurity.Login(userName, password, true)
                );

            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler(authConfig));
        }
```

Comment: read this http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/azure/

Comment: In order to help, please provide the following sections of your web.confg: `system.web\authentication`, `system.web\authorization`, `system.webserver\modules`, `system.identitymodel` and `system.identitymodel.services`

Comment: @DaveA I'm not using Identity Server. I've an API that requires authentication and is using Thinktecture.IdentityModel and   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity to validate each request.

Comment: @astaykov I don't have any setting related to those elements. Do I require any?

Comment: Are you using a single instance or more than one?

Comment: @leastprivilege I was using 2 instances, but just to test it, I switch it to only one and I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set a fixed signing key on the SessionTokenConfiguration. You definitely need that.

Comment: Thanks, just like you said.